# Bootstrap and Scrollbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Good day.
There is a project on Bootstrap 3 necessary to implement stylized  vertical scrollbar
Maybe there are some plugins specifically for Bootstrap or can advise that you can use instead?
Google did not give any recommendations.
Thank you)

Comment: A google search for 'stylized vertical scrollbar' will give you plenty of results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

repository: https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll